# Can the latest Sequelizejs (4.0.0-0) be integrated with ExpressJS

Tags: express, sequelize.js

Current version of Sequelizejs is `4.0.0-0`. And its docs has nothing about ExpressJS integration.

However virsion `1.7.0` has some tutorial about how to use Sequelizejs with ExpressJS http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/

Does current `4.0.0-0` version support ExpressJS? Where may I find best practices of integration?

Answer (score 1):

The article you referenced is still valid today. It works fine with Sequelize 4 which we use on a daily basis.

### Further references

There is a working [github example](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example) for integrating Sequelize into express.

Also, there is another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20591015/1027464.) giving a fabulous explanation of integrating the two.