# Where should I store my data models?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use sqlight to create a datamodel in a node-module:

database.js:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
    settings = require('./settings.js').settings,
    sequelize = new Sequelize(settings.database),
    //Datamodel
    User = sequelize.define('user', {
        authID:     Sequelize.STRING,
        name:       Sequelize.STRING,
    }),
    UserAttribute = sequelize.define('userAttributes', {
        name:       Sequelize.STRING,
        value:      Sequelize.STRING,
    }),
    Hail = sequelize.define('hail', {
        lat:        Sequelize.INTEGER,
        lon:        Sequelize.INTEGER,
    });

UserAttribute.belongsTo(User);
Hail.belongsTo(User, {as: 'driver'});
Hail.belongsTo(User, {as: 'rider'});

sequelize.sync(settings.sync).then(function() {
    return User.create({});
}).then(function(driver) {
  console.log(driver.get({
    plain: true
  }));
});
```

This works fine, but what if I want to access the models in another part of my application, like if I would like to create a user inside a controller. Where should i store them and what would be a good way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way of organizing apps having `Sequelize` models is creating a `models` package with `index.js` inside handling association and reading the models inside the package directory. Example:

- [`sequelize/express-example`](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/tree/master/models)

Also see @Farm's answer in this thread:

- [How to organize a node app that uses sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487416/how-to-organize-a-node-app-that-uses-sequelize)