# Error: db.sequelize.define is not a function in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to node and here I am going to map mysql to my node project.
**model/User.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../database/db.js')

module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
        user_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        first_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        last_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    }
);
```

In the above code `module.exports = db.sequelize.define()` an error comes as **db.sequelize.define is not a function**. What is the reason for this error in code?

**database/db.js**

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize")
const db = {}
const sequelize = new Sequelize("node","root","",{
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "mysql",
    operatorsAliases: false,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire:30000,
        idle:10000
    }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

Comment: Please check the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470508/sequelize-define-is-not-a-function?rq=1

Comment: Can you update the question and include the code of db.js?

Comment: @Runsis I edited the problem with db.js code.

Comment: OK, I found the problem and added an answer :D Kamalka! Hope you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.sequelize = sequelize
db.sequelize = Sequelize
```

This is what makes you the problems.
remove the 2nd line.
or change it to:

```
db.Sequelize = Sequelize
```

And then dont use

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
```

on your file, use db.Sequelize instead.

Comment: Thank you. db.**S**equelize = Sequelize this was the problem with my code. when I correct it works.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you have is in your database file `db.js` in the way you are defining and exporting sequelize. I recommend you to change it to this:

```
  const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
    const db = new Sequelize("node","root","",{
        host: "localhost",
        dialect: "mysql",
        operatorsAliases: false,
    
        pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            acquire:30000,
            idle:10000
        }
    })
    
    // I deleted what was causing the problem

    module.exports = db;
```

And in **model/User.js** you should just call `define()` with `db.define()`:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../database/db.js')

// I created an object here so you can export it
const User = db.define(
    'user',
    {
        user_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        first_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        last_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    }
);

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. I really appreciate it and I learned a lot.